# How to force http on specific folder in https site

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

I have site with https

But I need specific folder should be http.

How can we achieve it ?

e.g.
my site is

```
https://www.mywebsite.com
```

I want `folder1/subfolder1` should be forced to `http://`

e.g. `http://www.mywebsite.com/folder1/subfolder1`

I searched on net...but maximum search show how to force `http` to `https`

I tried `.htaccess` as follows :

```
 try 1.
RewriteRule ^(/folder1/subfolder1)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


 try 2.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/subfolder1
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]
```

But it didn't work..

Comment: Didn't you try something to do with .htaccess?

Comment: @semira yes , i tried...plz see edited question..

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force https on everything except /folder1/subfolder1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+folder1/subfolder1[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# force http on /folder1/subfolder1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+folder1/subfolder1[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.